# package.json alternative for a c# dotnet project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, package.json

in the nodejs project we have a package.json to inform some information about the project, version, author, description and etc, what would be the file for a dotnet project? would it be a package.json too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify this information directly in [the .csproj file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>Azure.Storage.Blobs</PackageId>
    <Version>12.4.0</Version>
    <Authors>your_name</Authors>
    <Company>your_company</Company>
    <PackageTags>Microsoft Azure Storage Blobs;Microsoft;Azure;Blobs;Blob;Storage;StorageScalable</PackageTags>
    <Description>
      This client library enables working with the Microsoft Azure Storage Blob service for storing binary and text data.
    </Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Or via [.nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file).

Comment: Oh man, thanks, sorry for the stupid question, I'm new to dotnet.

Comment: @Daniel NP, was glad to help!